# Excluir Imagem da Pasta

Tags: php

Tenho esse código PHP que me retorna todas as imagens dentro da pasta:

```
 <?php $files = glob("*.*"); for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++) { $num = $files[$i]; echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="ran
dom image">'."&nbsp;&nbsp;"; } ?>
```

Porém, teria algum jeito de colocar um botão de excluir em cada uma das fotos que aparecer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você adicionar um `anchor` com um parâmetro e depois verificar se o parâmetro foi passado, caso tenha sido, você utiliza a função `unlink` para remover.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

/* Verifica se o parâmetro `remove` foi passado na URL */
if (isset($_GET["remove"])) {

    /* Caso tenha sido passado, decodifica o parâmetro e remove o arquivo */
    unlink(base64_decode($_GET["remove"]));
}

$files = glob("*.*");

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) {
    $num = $files[$i];

    /**
     * Exibe a imagem com um `<a></a>`
     * No atributo `href`, basta utilizarmos o parâmetro `remove`
     * com o valor codificado em base64, isso evitará problemas
     * com caracteres especiais
     */
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" /><a href="?remove='.base64_encode($num).'">Remover</a><br>';
}

?>
```